# Cannot start a bounty on old problem?

Tags: support, status-completed, bounty

I was trying to put a bounty on [this old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186557/bounding-the-product-of-a-quadrilaterals-side-lengths-in-terms-of-the-lengths-o) of mine. I know there are some circumstances where bounties of certain amounts cannot be placed, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13211/why-cant-i-seem-to-start-a-bounty-on-my-question), but this does not seem to be one of those situations.

Can you see any reason why trying to add a bounty would lead me to the generic "Page not found" message?

Comment: The only reason is a bug in the system.

Comment: @Woodface: I see... Drat?

Comment: @MikeF I just tried to place a 50-rep bounty on it, but the same thing happened to me. It seems like the only choice they give you is the "[contact us](http://math.stackexchange.com/contact)" option--unless someone here knows a workaround.

Comment: This is not just you. [Bounties broken network-wide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252002)

Comment: Thanks, both, for taking the time to follow up. Thanks @Woodface for posting the issue to the Stackexchange meta.

Comment: Mike, @Woodface, when I try to load the bounty adding dialog, it's fine. When does the process breaks down?

Comment: @Asaf At the very last step, when you confirmed everything.

Comment: The fix for this bug is [in the pipeline](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252022).

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252002/bounties-broken-network-wide for details

Comment: @Woodface: Are you saying that the developers just flush bug fixes down the toilet?